# How to make autoIncrement number start with (001....009, 011......099)?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table

i have a challenge with my time in my work, i have feature class called "Parcel" storing many data, i generated an autoIncrement number by using field calculator, in field "parcel code"

`Expression:
autoIncrement()`

Expression Type:
PYTHON_9.3

Code Block:
rec=0
def autoIncrement():
 global rec
 pStart = 1 #adjust start value, if req'd 
 pInterval = 1 #adjust interval value, if req'd
 if (rec == 0): 
  rec = pStart 
 else: 
  rec = rec + pInterval 
 return rec

that i asked here before
[Adding automated values to attribute field?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31706/how-to-add-automate-values-to-attribute-field)

i want to start number to 001......009, and 010.........099,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `zfill` function, like in the code below, `zfill` function fill zeros in the left of the string:

```
Expression:
autoIncrement()

Expression Type:
PYTHON_9.3

Code Block:
rec=0
def autoIncrement():
 global rec
 pStart = 1 #adjust start value, if req'd 
 pInterval = 1 #adjust interval value, if req'd
 if (rec == 0): 
  rec = pStart 
 else: 
  rec = rec + pInterval 
 return str(rec).zfill(3)
```

Comment: wooooooooooooooow, thank you very much @geogeek, you solved spend many time, instead of doing it manually, thank you again.

Comment: Here is a version that uses a generator function rather then a `if` and `global` https://gist.github.com/NathanW2/8113514

Comment: ok, thank you very much@Nathan W, it is a good idea.