# Adding both string and automated numbers in series to attribute table using ArcGIS field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I would like to fill a column in my attribute table with an string that ends in a numeric value.

Example:

- Object001
- Object002
- Object003

I would like to automate the process of filling in the attribute table.

There is a great post on [Adding automated values to attribute field?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31706) made previously that explains how to add numbers in series to an attribute table. I would like to build on this code by adding a string invfront of the number.

I'm trying to combine the python code found in the above post with a string but it isn't working. See below for the code which will add a series.

```
    Expression:
autoIncrement()

Expression Type:
PYTHON_9.3

Code Block:
rec=0
def autoIncrement():
 global rec
 pStart = 1 #adjust start value, if req'd 
 pInterval = 1 #adjust interval value, if req'd
 if (rec == 0): 
  rec = pStart 
 else: 
  rec = rec + pInterval 
 return rec
```

However when I try and combine the code in the field like below, I just get an error.

```
'Object'autoIncrement()   

**or**  

'Object' & autoIncrement()
```

My syntax is wrong but I'm not quite sure how to correct it.

Comment: "Object"+str (autoincrement ()).zfill (3). Replace 3 with 4 if you have more than 1000 and less than 9999 records

Answer (score 4):

We can adjust the Field Calculator Code Block to achieve the effect you are looking for. The following assumes that your target field is a Text Field, and has enough length to hold the value produced by the Field Calculation. For example, if we want to prefix our incremental count with the word "Object":

```
Expression:
autoIncrement("Object")

Expression Type:
PYTHON_9.3

Code Block:
rec=0
def autoIncrement(string_prefix):
 global rec
 pStart = 1 #adjust start value, if req'd 
 pInterval = 1 #adjust interval value, if req'd
 if (rec == 0): 
  rec = pStart 
 else: 
  rec = rec + pInterval 
 return string_prefix + str(rec)
```

This process should yield the following results into your target Text Field:

```
"Object1"
"Object2"
... and so on
```

Adding the "Object *001*" (the leading zeros) will be a little more complicated, but it is possible. You would need to find a way to write the leading zero's based on the total number of records in the table, for example, if the table has 5000 records, you would need something like "Object *0001*" and so on...

Comment: Jim Thank you so much for your response.  I ended up solving this a slightly different way before I found your response. Finding a response from geogeek about number padding [See Here] I was able to use this code in the code block and then I added the syntax that @FelixIP suggested in the field below the pre-logic script code box which was: 'Object' + str(autoIncrement()) Thanks for the help.  [1] [1]:http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81316/how-to-make-autoincrement-number-start-with-001-009-011-099?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Solved this using a combination of everyone's suggestions:

Code Block -

```
rec=0
def autoIncrement():
global rec
pStart = 1 #adjust start value, if req'd 
pInterval = 1 #adjust interval value, if req'd
if (rec == 0): 
rec = pStart 
else: 
rec = rec + pInterval 
return str(rec).zfill(3)
```

In the Field Expression -

```
 'Object' + str(autoIncrement())
```