# How do I order polygons so their IDs are contiguous from NW to SE?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcmap

Census Tract IDs are ordered in large areas, but patchy across the state. I need to assign a new ID that flows in an order from one end to the opposite end (i.e, NW to SE) where polygons are touching. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Use [Feature To Point (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003m000000) to create a point inside each polygon (check the Inside box to make sure the generated points are inside your polygons). Then use [Add XY Coordinates (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//001700000032000000) to add the XY coordinates for each point. Add a new field as double and do this field calculation: X^2 + Y^2. Sort the points attribute table based on the newly created field (descending or ascending depending on the location of your data) and create related IDs in a separate field, you may find this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31706/how-to-add-automate-values-to-attribute-field) useful. Finally use [Spatial Join (Analysis)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000) or intersect the points with the polygons and get their IDs using join/relates for your polygons.

Comment: just a small remark : X^2 + Y^2 will correspond to circles centered on the origin of your reference system. You may need to use (X-Xb)^2 + (Y-Yb)^2 to put a false origin as far as you can from your area of interest (so that your curve are closer to straight lines, and you avoid considering (0,100) and (0, -100) equal )

Comment: This makes sense. I agree.

Comment: @radouxju what is the Xb and Yb of a given location?