# Calculating sequential values in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, calculate-values, sequential

Previous posts (such as [Adding automated values to attribute field?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31706)) answer how to calculate sequential values in an attribute table.  The posts all seem to rely on the process described in this ESRI Tech Support page:

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011137

Here are the article's details:

> 1. Create a new short integer field.
> 2. Set the Parser to Python.
> 3. Select Show Codeblock.
> 4. Paste the following into the Pre-Logic Script Code:
>
>    ```
>    rec=0 
>    def autoIncrement(): 
>     global rec 
>     pStart = 1  
>     pInterval = 1 
>     if (rec == 0):  
>      rec = pStart  
>     else:  
>      rec += pInterval  
>     return rec
>    ```
> 5. Paste the following code in the smaller box below the Pre-Logic Script Code:
>
>    ```
>    autoIncrement()
>    ```
> 6. Click OK.

But at 10.5.1 I can achieve the same results with this single line in the field calculator:

**!FID! + 1**

The results are exactly the same as the more complex ESRI-supplied code, even if the the table is sorted on a non-FID field and/or there is a selected set of records.

What am I missing here?  Does the ESRI-supplied code do something that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Fid + 1 valid for shapefiles only. Edited feature class in database will likely fail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Esri supplied code starts from `0` and increases by `1`.  Your method will do the same *only* if your `FID` starts at `0` and increases sequentially.  An ObjectID or FID is system managed, so if you delete a record you will have gaps, and in a geodatabase you could have a feature class that has an ObjectID starting at `300000` (for example), so you're not going to get a straight `1`,`2`,`3`,`4` etc. from that using your code.

Comment: To add to this. The ESRI code will work on a selection. The FID + 1 won't. So has a few more applications.